# Issue with Decorator design pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to use decorator pattern here. BaseCart is abstract class. Cart extends BaseCart and gets total price. Now I want to give discount on total cart value without changing the existing code. So I created CartDecorator which extends BaseCart and then created TotalDiscountCart which will get total amount and then apply discount on it.

Now I am trying to run unit test given below is not giving correct output. Product is added in cart but when Cart's getTotalPrice() method is called then productsWithQuantity is empty. 
Shouldn't it have values added? Why is it empty and how to solve it?

```
    public abstract class BaseCart {


        Map<Product, Integer> productsWithQuantity = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
        Double totalPrice = 0.0;

        public void addProduct(Product product, Integer quantity){
            productsWithQuantity.put(product, quantity);
        }

        public abstract Double getTotalPrice();
    }


    public class Cart extends BaseCart{

        @Override
        public Double getTotalPrice() {
            productsWithQuantity.forEach((product ,quantity )-> totalPrice = totalPrice + product.getUnitPrice() * quantity);
            return totalPrice;
        }


    }


public class CartDecorator extends BaseCart{

    BaseCart cart;

    public CartDecorator(BaseCart cart) {
        super();
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getTotalPrice() {
        return this.cart.getTotalPrice();
    }

}

public class TotalDiscountCart extends CartDecorator{

    public TotalDiscountCart(BaseCart cart) {
        super(cart);
    }

    @Override
    public Double getTotalPrice() {
        super.getTotalPrice();
        return totalPrice - (percentDiscount(10.0));

    }

    private Double percentDiscount(Double i) {
        return 0.1 * totalPrice;
    }


}

    @Test
    public void shouldGiveDiscountOf9() {
        //Given
        BaseCart cart = new TotalDiscountCart(new Cart());

        Product productDove = new Product("Dove soap", 30.0);

        //when
        cart.addProduct(productDove, 3);

        // then
        assertEquals(Double.valueOf(81.0),cart.getTotalPrice());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delegate `addProduct` to `cart` in `CartDecorator`. It would also probably make sense to create a `Cart` interface as `CartDecorator` does not profit from subclassing `BaseCart`.

> Can you please elaborate this 'create a Cart interface as CartDecorator does not profit from subclassing BaseCart.'?

Your `BaseCart` actually does two things. One is defining an interface to work with carts (consisting of `addProduct` and `getTotalPrice` methods). The other is provide a basic implementation for `addProduct` which fills the `productsWithQuantity` map.

Now a `CartDecorator` decorates another cart. It (of course) should implement the same interface as all carts do. But for the `CartDecorator` it is actually counterproductive to inherit the `addProduct` implementation from the `BaseCart`. Because `CartDecorator` could delegate `addProduct` to the decorated cart - so it actually does not need its own `productsWithQuantity` map etc.

This is why it might make sense to define the `Cart` interface and if you think you need it a basic abstract implementation like `BaseCart`. The `CartDecorator` then would implement the `Cart` interface but not extend `BaseCart`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this 'create a Cart interface as CartDecorator does not profit from subclassing BaseCart.'?